# Android some action when button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I want to rotate my object when I **PRESS_DOWN** button and stop rotating when I **PRESS_UP**. 
I tried to do it with **OnTouchListener** but seems there is no way to kmow that button is still pressed. 
For example I touch button 1st time, and there is 1st touch event raised with **ACTION_DOWN**, but then if I keep my finger not moving nothing will happen (no more events). Or if I will move it very fast there will be different speed of raising on touch event ACTION_MOVE. Different speed that depends on finger's speed moves is unacceptable for my task. So I decided to **start timer** (that do rotating with fixed speed) when **ACTION_DOWN** raised and to **cancel TimerTask when ACTION_UP** is raised, it works good, just like I need. But I think it's not the best solution or even the worst. Please give me an advice of other possible solutions.

Comment: Why don't you use android animations to rotate your object? It's fairly easy to start and end rotating on a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution of using a timer is good, and is what you are supposed to you.
If you are running an animation, you cannot rely on UI events, you have to have a separate thread or timer for periodic updates.

Answer (score 1):

Using timer is a good way. To my knowledge, I think using a simple if-else may solve your problem more efficiently. For example,

```
boolean state = true;
if(state)
{
 // do the code for ACTION_DOWN
}
else
{
 // do the code for ACTION_UP
state = true;
}
```

Give a loop to this if statement, as many times you want. But I don't know, whether this solution meets your requirements, or not.